# Error creating and injecting BCryptPasswordEncoder in a service class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I want to hash and store the password in the database. When I try to inject the PasswordEncoder bean into my service class, I get the error mentioned below.

This is my first project using the Spring-security module and would appreciate your advice.

```
Spring Boot version:2.2.6.RELEASE
```

**SecurityConfiguration.java: security configuration class*

```
 @EnableWebSecurity
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.sd.authandauthorizationbackendapp.security" })
    public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean())
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService).
                .and().authenticationProvider(authProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/test").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .and().formLogin();
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10, new SecureRandom());
    }
    }
```

**UserServiceImpl.java: a service class to save user**

```
 @Service
    public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    public void save(User user) {
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.
                                  encode(user.getPassword()));
        user.setRoles(user.getRoles());
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
    }
```

**ERROR**

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bCryptPasswordEncoder';   Error creating 
bean with name 'passwordEncoder': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an 
unresolvable circular reference?
```

Please let me know if further code and details are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you use `@Qualified("passwordEncoder")` in the service class then spring will look for `bCryptPasswordEncoder` as bean. At the moment you are looking for a bean called `bCryptPasswordEncoder`.

Change it to

```
  @Autowired
  PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
```

or

```
 @Qualified("passwordEncoder")
 @Autowired
 PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
```

Comment: Thank you, the project runs now. However, when I run the application, I get NPE for the PasswordEncoder bean. Any idea why is that occurring?

Comment: when the save() method executes in UserServiceImpl class  and tries to use the encode() method of the PasswordEncoder bean.

Comment: are you sure it is the encoder and not the user that is null?

Comment: The authentication is working now and I will post an answer. However, the authorization is failing for USER role and passing for ADMIN role. Any idea why would that be?

Comment: This issue us also fixed now. I will post a complete solution.

Answer (score -1):

By removing `@Autowired` from `PasswordEncoder` the problem will be going to resolve.
As you’re creating the PasswordEncoder in the same class that you’re injecting it.